# Mi listview flotante no muestra datos en xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

El problema consiste en que no muestra datos el listview que son traídos desde una base de datos local (sql server) pero a la hora de depurar no se ve nada, aunque si llena las casillas del listview. aclaro que este listview lo cree de manera flotante dentro de un formulario, me percate que cuando lo esto depurando y me dirijo al xaml en la parte de los labels si cambio la siglas
Text="{Binding Codsito.codigo}"  por Text="{Binding codigo}"  ay si puedo ver los datos pero si intento depurarlo nueva mente me arroja este error

`XFC0045    Binding: Property "codigo" not found on "app_Makariza.Entidad.rootModel".   app_Makariza    D:\proyecto_App\app_Makariza\app_Makariza\Presentacion\Mantenimiento.xaml   595 Compilación`

Lo que quiero en si es poder visualizar los datos tampronto me muestre el listview sin tener que estar borrando codigo para ver la lista

```
xaml
 <Grid x:Name="rosas" 
       Grid.Row="0"
       BackgroundColor="#8000"
       Padding="20" 
       IsVisible="false" 
       HeightRequest="200"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       >

     <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" >

         <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#8000"
                      IsVisible="true">
             
             <Grid RowDefinitions="40,*,70" Margin="10" IsVisible="true" >
                 <Label Text="CODIGO DE MANTENIMIENTO" 
                        TextColor="White" 
                        FontSize="Title" 
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        Grid.Row="0"
                  />

                 <ListView x:Name="Codigo"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding CodList}" 
                           SelectedItem="{Binding Codsito}"
                           ItemSelected="Codigo_ItemSelected"
                           HasUnevenRows="True"
                           IsVisible="true"
                           HeightRequest="500"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                            >

                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate >
                             <ViewCell   >
                                 <StackLayout IsVisible="true"  BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" >

                                     <Grid ColumnDefinitions="50,*" 
                                           RowDefinitions="25,25" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                           Margin="5"
                                           IsVisible="true">

                                         <Label Text="{Binding Codsito.codigo}"  
                                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                                FontSize="Title" 
                                                TextColor="Red" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                IsVisible="true"
                                                Grid.Row="0"
                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                />

                                         <Label Text="{Binding Codsito.falla_mecanica}" 
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                FontSize="Medium"
                                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                                TextColor="Black"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                IsVisible="true"
                                                Grid.Row="0"/>
                                     </Grid>
                                 </StackLayout>
                             </ViewCell>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListView>

                 <Button Grid.Row="2" 
                         Text="salir"
                         FontSize="Title"
                         FontAttributes="Bold"
                         Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                         CornerRadius="50"
                         Margin="10"
                         BackgroundColor="IndianRed"/>

             </Grid>
         </StackLayout>

     </ScrollView>

 </Grid>
```

De esta manera consulto los datos en la sql server

```
public List<Codigo> codt()
{
    Conexion.abrir();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cod_mantenimiento", Conexion.conectar);
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<Codigo> list = new List<Codigo>();


    while (rdr.Read())
    {

        Codigo objDatosTipos = new Codigo();
        objDatosTipos.id_codigo_mantenimiento = int.Parse(rdr["id_codigo_mantenimiento"].ToString());
        objDatosTipos.falla_mecanica = rdr["falla_mecanica"].ToString();
        objDatosTipos.responsable = rdr["responsable"].ToString();
        objDatosTipos.controles = rdr["controles"].ToString();
        objDatosTipos.procedimiento = rdr["procedimiento"].ToString();
        objDatosTipos.codigo = rdr["codigo"].ToString();
        list.Add(objDatosTipos);


    }
    Conexion.cerrar();
    rdr.Close();

    

    return list;
}
```

clase del root model

```
 public class rootModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

     //codigos
     List<Codigo> cod;
     public List<Codigo> CodList
     {
         get { return cod; }
         set
         {
             if (cod != value)
             {
                 cod = value;
                 OnPropertyChange();
             }

         }

     }
      Codigo codsito;

     public Codigo Codsito
     {

         get { return codsito; }
         set
         {
             if (codsito != value)
             {
                 codsito = value;
                
                 OnPropertyChange();
             }


         }
     }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }

    }

}
```

entidades que uso para los datos

```
 public class Codigo
 {
     public int id_codigo_mantenimiento { get; set; }
     public string falla_mecanica { get; set; }
     public string procedimiento { get; set; }
     public string responsable { get; set; }
     public string recursos { get; set; }
     public string controles { get; set; }
     public string codigo { get; set; }



 }
```

adjunto imagen de como se muestra el listview cuando no borro el dato del label Text="{Binding Codsito.codigo}"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

haci se veria cuando cambio el dato  Text="{Binding Codsito.codigo}" por Text="{Binding codigo}" mientras esta depurando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aclaro que soy nuevo en este tema de programación